# Is there a way (i.e. URL parameter) to force duckduckgo to only show results with ALL SEARCH TERMS

Tags: duckduckgo

Maybe it is a recent change, but it seems that duckduck.go has started to return search results, containing pages, that do not indeed contain ALL THE SEARCH TERMS, of the query.

This question looks for a way how to use https://duckduckgo.com/lite in a way that only yields results, being pages that actually contain all the searched for words.

The site https://duckduckgo.com/params does however not really help me here, even though I would think it is a feature that ddg can provide.

**UPDATE:**

I have found https://duck.co/help/results/syntax, which I referes to some search syntax as this:

> DuckDuckGo supports search syntax you can use to fine-tune your
> queries.
> Search operators:
>
> - `Example`  Result
> - `cats dogs`    Results about cats or dogs
> - `"cats and dogs"`  Results for exact term "cats and dogs"
> - `cats -dogs`   Fewer dogs in results
> - `cats +dogs`   More dogs in results cats
> - `filetype:pdf`     PDFs about cats. Supported file types: pdf, doc(x), xls(x), ppt(x), html
> - `dogs site:example.com`    Pages about dogs from example.com
> - `cats -site:example.com` Pages about cats, excluding example.com
> - `intitle:dogs`     Page title includes the word "dogs"
> - `inurl:cats`   Page url includes the word "cats"

This would lead me to believe that duckduckgo.com cannot provide functionality and is indeed missing a crucial feature.

However, it is unclear if `https://duck.co/` is indeed connected to `https://duckduckgo.com` in the first place

### Update 2

I have not found any way where this is documented. However it seems that by wrapping each individual search term in quotes, i.e. doing this search
`"require" "all" "search" "terms"` one can produce the desired effect.

- [https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q="require"+"all"+"search"+"terms"](https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=%22require%22%20%22all%22%20%22search%22%20%22terms%22) => shows results that indeed contain all words searched for.
- [https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=require+all+search+terms](https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=require%20all%20search%20terms) => will show search results that only contain some of the words (which may be usefult sometimes, but really complicates searches where the *adult* person knows perfectly well what she/he is doing, and needs not second guessing from duckduckgo.com)

Comment: what do you mean by `ALL THE SEARCH TERMS` can you provide an example?

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER imagine you search for a page containing the words `require` `all` `search` `terms`. You hence would do this [https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=require+all+search+terms](https://duckduckgo.com/lite?q=require+all+search+terms} which however would not yield pages that contain all the search words. The second result shown to me is [How to Do a Boolean Search in Google - Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/boolean-search-terms-google-1616810) which does not contain the word `require`.  It should hence have not shown in the results.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's the only proper way how to search for multiple exact "phrases" since:

```
"require all search terms"
```

will return you match for the whole phrase, eg. having:

```
"require" "all" "search" "terms"
```

shall return search results for all 4 phrases found per location.